# how to count number of files in zipfile in c#

Tags: c#, zip

Please tell me how to count the number of files in ZIP file.

I need a C# code to do this job in visual studio. Tried many codes when I Googled but getting an error saying:

> The namespace or assembly is not found for ZIPENTRY/ZIPFILE.

Can anyone tell me what i should include/anything need to be installed/provide me any code to count the number of files?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241889/i-didnt-find-zipfile-class-in-the-system-io-compression-namespace

Comment: thanks vadmin...i searched here also but couldnt get this link

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of files in a Zip File with c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785391/count-number-of-files-in-a-zip-file-with-c-sharp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241889/i-didnt-find-zipfile-class-in-the-system-io-compression-namespace/42531985#42531985

Answer (score 6):

As MSDN puts it (.Net 4.5) you can use **ZipArchive** and **ZipFile** classes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx

the classes being both in *System.IO.Compression* namespace are in different assemblies
*System.IO.Compression* and *System.IO.Compression.FileSystem* though.

so you may add references to **System.IO.Compression** and **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem** assemblies to your project and try something like this:

```
...
using System.IO.Compression; 
...


  // Number of files within zip archive
  public static int ZipFileCount(String zipFileName) {
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read)) {
      int count = 0;

      // We count only named (i.e. that are with files) entries
      foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
          count += 1;

      return count;
    }
  }
```

Another possibility is to use DotNetZip library, see:

[Count number of files in a Zip File with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785391/count-number-of-files-in-a-zip-file-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Use below:

```
using var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
var totalFiles = zip.Entries.Where(x=>x.Length>0).Count()
```

Folder do not have any Length

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

```
using DotNetZip;

int count;
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(path))
    count = zip.Count;
```

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785391/count-number-of-files-in-a-zip-file-with-c-sharp/4785405#4785405).

Comment: Sorry, but according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx ZipFile is a static class, no ZipFile zip = ... is possible

Comment: Did you get this code from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4785405/21567) answer? If so please indicate that (and add the part about "DotNetZip", which would at least make your code valid, regarding @DmitryBychenko's comment)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add references **System.IO.Compression** and **System.IO.Compression.FileSystem** to your project

```
using (var archive = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(filePath, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    var count = archive.Entries.Count(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Name));
}
```